# Evitar muitas requisições no Select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber alguma alternativa para bloquear as requisições em excesso com Select combo box do seguinte código:

```
    //Input Cascata Estado / Cidade
$("select[name='estado_id']").change(function(){
var estado_id = $(this).val();
var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
$("select[name='cidade_id'").html('<option value="0">Aguarde...</option>');
    $.ajax({
        url: "{!! route('admin.select.bairro_cidade')!!}",
        method: 'POST',
        data: {estado_id:estado_id, _token:token},
        success: function(data) {
            $("select[name='cidade_id'").html(data.options);
        }
    });
});
```

Por exemplo, quando o usuário fica navegando no select com as SETAS do teclado, cada vez que ele mudar o estado vai gerar uma requisição Ajax, o que pode gerar muitas requisições em um curto intervalo na página.
Tentei usar o focusout, porém ao mudar o selec para o próximo gera o bug de não carregar corretamente, tendo que clicar novamente no próximo select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desabilite o select que dispara o evento `change` enquanto o AJAX é processado e volte a habilitá-lo após o processamento do AJAX. Isso impede gargalo de processamentos se o usuário ficar alterando a opção rapidamente.

Mas volte a habilitar o select dentro de um callback `complete` (e não no `success`), porque se houver algum erro (ex., falha na comunicação com o servidor) o `complete` será executado mesmo assim, voltando a habilitar o select.

É preciso também armazenar o elemento que disparou o `change` numa variável para poder referenciá-lo dentro da função do `complete`:

```
$("select[name='estado_id']").change(function(){
   var t = this; // armazena o elemento na variável
   t.disabled = true; // desabilita o select
   var estado_id = t.value;
   var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
   $("select[name='cidade_id'").html('<option value="0">Aguarde...</option>');
    $.ajax({
        url: "{!! route('admin.select.bairro_cidade')!!}",
        method: 'POST',
        data: {estado_id:estado_id, _token:token},
        success: function(data) {
            $("select[name='cidade_id'").html(data.options);
        },
        complete: function(){
           t.disabled = false; // volta a habilitar o select
        }
    });
});
```

## Edit

Seria interessante também tratar possíveis erros, como de conexão, por exemplo. Para isso use o callback `error`, onde você pode voltar o select dos Estados para a primeira opção e exibir uma mensagem no segundo select:

```
$("select[name='estado_id']").change(function(){
   var t = this; // armazena o elemento na variável
   var cidades = $("select[name='cidade_id'"); // armazena o select das cidades
   var estado_id = t.value;
   var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
   t.disabled = true; // desabilita o select
   cidades.html('<option value="0">Aguarde...</option>');
    $.ajax({
        url: "{!! route('admin.select.bairro_cidade')!!}",
        method: 'POST',
        data: {estado_id:estado_id, _token:token},
        success: function(data) {
            cidades.html(data.options);
        },
        complete: function(){
           t.disabled = false; // volta a habilitar o select
        },
        error: function(){
           t.selectedIndex = 0; // volta o select para o primeiro option
           cidades.html("<option value='0'>Houve um problema!</option>"); // coloca um option com uma mensagem
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Testei e não completou o select dos municípios desse modo, acho q a ideia o timeout pode ser viável

Comment: @RafaelMeirim Esqueci de colocar `data.options` no `$("select[name='cidade_id'").html(data.options)`. Teste agora que deve funcionar.

Comment: @RafaelMeirim Vou editar a resposta com uma solução mais completa prevendo possíveis erros.

Comment: Muito bom, fiz umas alterações para ser exibido corretamente e no complete dei um focus no estado_id para que volte a habilitar as setas (caso o usuário selecione por esse método)